# Regression against polynomials and log-linear predictors

Tags: regression, lognormal-distribution, polynomial

I have a regression problem where one of the predictors has a very good fit as $Y \sim poly(X_1, 2)$.
However, $Y$ is clearly log-linear against my second predictor $X_2$, so $ln(Y) \sim ln(X_2)$.

How should I model $Y \sim X_1 + X_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean $\ln(Y) \sim X_{2}$ (i.e. *log* in $Y$ but *linear* in $X_{2}$)?

If so, then exponentiating both sides gives $Y \sim e^{X_{2}}$, so for both $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$

$Y \sim \text{poly}(X_{1},2) + e^{X_{2}}$

On the other hand if you did indeed mean $\ln(Y) \sim \ln(X_{2})$, then:

$Y \sim X_{2}$ for $X_{2} > 0$, so

$Y \sim \text{poly}(X_{1},2) + X_{2}$ for $X_{2} > 0$.

Comment: Do you mean that regressing Y ~ X2 is equivalent to ln(Y) ~ ln(X2), for X2 > 0?

Comment: @RobertKubrick Yep. $e^{\ln(Y)} = Y$ and $e^{\ln(X_{2})} = X_{2}$. You can exponentiate both sides of a regression equation. **Question, though:** why do you describe $\ln(Y) \sim \ln(X_{2})$ as *log-linear* rather than *log-log*?

Comment: @RobertKubrick I am, of course, leaving out discussion of distribution of errors. Can talk about that also, if need be.

Comment: Yes, I really meant log-log. I ended up with $ln(Y) \sim ln(X_2)$ for the reason you are hinting to, residuals heteroskedasticity. Using the untransformed $Y$ fan out the residuals. How should I approach this problem then?

Comment: You can use the form from my second suggestion, but estimate using a *mixed model* to explicitly account for/model heteroscedasticity, *a la* $Y = \beta_{0} + \mathbf{B}\text{poly}(X_{1},2) + \beta_{X_{2}}X_{2} + \varepsilon_{0} + \varepsilon_{X_{2}}X_{2}$, where $\varepsilon_{0}$ and $\varepsilon_{X_{2}}$ are distributed, say, [Wishart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution), each with it's own variance term, and a single covariance between them.

Comment: Great thank you for your help. Do you have some reference (books or online) to learn more about mixed models?

Comment: @RobertKubrick A decent introductory text to multilevel modeling, (e.g. Goldstein, H. (2003). *Multilevel statistical models*. Oxford University Press, 3rd edition.) are good. A mixed model is like a single-level multilevel model, where you are modeling variance as a function of predictors. You will probably want to steer a bit away from those by Raudenbush and friends, who motivate "hierarchical linear models" in such a way that first (bottom) level heteroscedasticity is ignored.

Comment: I rerun my regression as $Y \sim X_2$ and $ln(Y) \sim ln(X_2)$, expecting to see the same $R^2$. Instead I got two different values, 0.23 and 0.19 respectively. How can that be if the two models are equivalent?

Comment: Posted a new question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142109/is-y-sim-x-equivalent-to-lny-sim-lnx

Comment: @Alexis log-linear is often used to mean "linear in the logs", so Robert's use of the expression "log-linear" in the way he did isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: @Glen_b Didn't say he was. Was just curious, 'cause I have seen it used the other way (e.g. on graphs, for instance).

Comment: @RobertKubrick Remember that bit about the distribution of residuals? :)

Comment: @Alexis Yes, if you're talking about possibly transforming the two variables, as here, then it makes perfect sense to think of it in terms of listing the two transformations just as one would with a scatterplot.