# Is $Y \sim X$ equivalent to $ln(Y) \sim ln(X)$?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, least-squares

I read in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142008/regression-against-polynomials-and-log-linear-predictors) that $Y \sim X$ is equivalent to $ln(Y) \sim ln(X)$ (assuming $X>0$ and without considering standard error issues). Indeed OLS theory says that heteroskedasticity of the residuals does not imply a [bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity#Consequences) in the estimators.

Then why do I get a different $R^2$ for the same data after applying a log transformation to both $X$ and $Y$?

```
> summary(lm(Y ~ X, t))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = t)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-85.97  -5.85  -1.44   1.21 147.35 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.30740    0.15765   -1.95               0.051 .  
X            0.10476    0.00123   84.98 <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17.7 on 23473 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.235, Adjusted R-squared:  0.235 
F-statistic: 7.22e+03 on 1 and 23473 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002

> summary(lm(log(Y) ~ log(X), t))

Call:
lm(formula = log(Y) ~ log(X), data = t)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-6.680 -1.084 -0.031  1.302  3.033 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -2.4160     0.0417   -57.9 <0.0000000000000002 ***
log(X)        0.7759     0.0102    76.4 <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.63 on 23473 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.199, Adjusted R-squared:  0.199 
F-statistic: 5.83e+03 on 1 and 23473 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```

Comment: It is stated clearly [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression#Invariance_to_monotone_transformations) that this property doesn't hold in general for linear regression.

Comment: What does $y\sim x$ mean?

Comment: @mpiktas Y regressed against X.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think carefully about what $y\sim x$ means.

If you're putting a model like that into `lm`, it implies:

$y = \beta_0+\beta_1 x+\eta$

but $\log(y)\sim \log(x)$ implies

$\log(y) = \gamma_0+\gamma_1 \log(x)+\eta$

exponentiate both sides:

$\:y = \exp(\gamma_0)\,\exp(\gamma_1 \log(x))\,\exp(\eta)$

$\quad = \alpha_0\,x^{\gamma_1}\,\zeta$

[image]

That's not at all the same sort of model for $y$ to my eyes!

(There's one situation where -- aside from the effect of the error term -- the models correspond - the intercept terms are both zero and the slope terms are both 1.)

Comment: So not the same at all, even if I remove the intercept right?